# Filtering a view using three bit columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

The view can be filtered on these three columns:

```
Profit(bit), Loss(bit), NoImpact(bit)
```

Backstory: On a webpage a user can choose to filter the data based on three checkboxes (Profit, Loss, No impact).

What I am looking for: If they check 'Profit' return everything where 'Profit' = 1, if then they check 'Loss' show 'Profit' AND 'Loss' results but exclude 'NoImpact', and so forth.

This is what I've tried so far and part of my stored proc:

```
WHERE (
   ((@ProfitSelected is null OR @ProfitSelected = 'false') OR (Profit = @ProfitSelected))
   --I've tried using AND here as well.
   OR ((@LossSelected is null OR @LossSelected = 'false') OR (Loss = @LossSelected))
   OR ((@NoImpactSelected is null OR @NoImpactSelected = 'false') OR (NoImpact = @NoImpactSelected))
)

END


exec dbo.SearchErrorReports @ProfitSelected = 1, @LossSelected = 1, @NoImpactSelected = 0
```

Thank you.

EDIT: As requested here are some tests and desired results:

**TEST** `exec dbo.SearchErrorReports @ProfitSelected = 1, @LossSelected = 1, @NoImpactSelected = 0`

**Result**

```
id | Profit   | Loss   | NoImpact
----------------------------------------
 1 | 1        | 0      | 0
 2 | 1        | 0      | 0
 3 | 0        | 1      | 0
 4 | 0        | 1      | 0
 5 | 0        | 1      | 0
```

**TEST** `exec dbo.SearchErrorReports @ProfitSelected = 0, @LossSelected = 1, @NoImpactSelected = 0`

**Result**

```
id | Profit   | Loss   | NoImpact
----------------------------------------
 1 | 0        | 1      | 0
 2 | 0        | 1      | 0
 3 | 0        | 1      | 0
```

**TEST** `exec dbo.SearchErrorReports @ProfitSelected = 1, @LossSelected = 1, @NoImpactSelected = 1`

**Result**

```
id | Profit   | Loss   | NoImpact
----------------------------------------
 1 | 1        | 0      | 0
 2 | 0        | 1      | 0
 3 | 0        | 1      | 0
 4 | 0        | 0      | 1
 5 | 1        | 0      | 0
 6 | 0        | 0      | 1
```

Etc and all the different permutations.

Comment: You confuse "bit" and "boolean", though the database engine might convert between them for you. But don't develop lazy habit of relying on implicit conversion - bit is 0, 1, or null. Erland discusses [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) at great length.

Comment: @SMor I thought "bit" was a representation of "boolean" in sql. Thank you for the resource, I am going through it now.

Comment: What are the expected results if `@NoImpact =  1`?

Comment: @Zhorov if  `@NoImpactSelected = 1` and rest were 0, then show only rows where NoImpact is true. If all were 1 then show everything. I would also like to show everything when nothing is selected - meaning all params are set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the following `WHERE` clause should return the expected results:

```
WHERE 
    (@ProfitSelected = 1 AND Profit = 1) OR
    (@LossSelected = 1 AND Loss = 1) OR
    (@NoImpactSelected = 1 AND NoImpact = 1) OR
    (@ProfitSelected = 0 AND @LossSelected = 0 AND @NoImpactSelected = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But when I try `@ProfitSelected = 1, @LossSelected = 1, @NoImpactSelected = 0`, I get 0 results. Though when an individual param is set to 1, it works. Multiple selection does not work.

Comment: I will try, I dont know how to create table in comments. So if `@ProfitSelected = 1, @LossSelected = 1, @NoImpactSelected = 0` **Result:**  Show all results where Profit = 1, Loss = 1, NoImpact =0.  if `@ProfitSelected = 0, @LossSelected = 1, @NoImpactSelected = 1` **Result:**  Show all results where Profit = 0, Loss = 1, NoImpact =1. if `@ProfitSelected = 0, @LossSelected = 0, @NoImpactSelected = 1` **Result:**  Show all results where Profit = 0, Loss = 0, NoImpact=1. I guess you can call it permutations?

Comment: I added some tests and the desired results I am looking for, in my question. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209943/discussion-between-noonmoon-and-zhorov).

Answer (score 0):

@Zhorov helped me a lot. I had to modify his query slightly to have all test cases covered:

```
WHERE (@ProfitSelected = 0 AND @LossSelected = 0 AND @NoImpactSelected = 0) OR
    (@ProfitSelected = 1 AND Profit = 1) OR
    (@LossSelected = 1 AND Loss = 1) OR
    (@NoImpactSelected = 1 AND NoImpact = 1) OR
    (@ProfitSelected = 1 AND @LossSelected = 1 AND @NoImpactSelected = 1)
```